# Swithcing of Threads

Tags: vb.net

I have vb.net application that acts like a Server(Echo) and it allows clients(another application) to query the server for different type of documents or other files.Now the problem that I am facing now is that when the application(Server) is UP,it runs on a single thread.But when a client from same machine or some other machine tries to connect to the server to query,the application starts another thread for the connection established with the server.Hence, while debugging the Server(VB.Net application),we find the the control switches from the operations being performed on one thread that started from the time the Server is up to the other thread which is started when the client connects to the Server.But I want the entire operation to be done on the same thread that was started from the moment the server was UP.

The second thread that is started once the client tries to connect to the server is because we are Using a thrid party control name Dart TCP for the connection between Server and Client,where in for a client to connect to the Server,we are using a method which is called in an **Initialize** method like the below code when the client connects:

server.start(New ConnectThreadStart(AddressOf **connectionstart**),port,state).
Here,**connectionstart** is the method  which starts the connection and is resposible for the communication between the server and the client till any one of the two ends the connection.

Any solution or ideas provided will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to check - the Dart you are referring to is the control from dart.com, and nothing to do with Google's Dart language (the `Dart` tag added refers to Google Dart).

Comment: This is all pretty normal when you have more than one thread executing code, particularly if they execute the same method.  Which is expected if both threads handle a network connection.  Sure, debugging is more difficult, a breakpoint can be hit by both threads.  Just make sure it works perfectly for one connection first.  You can freeze a thread with the Debug + Windows + Threads debugger window.

Answer (score 0):

As you see, there's a new thread started with a new request (this is good).

One (quite bad) way to make all the threads share some configuration settings is to use a thread-safe variable in which you store the configuration. When a thread needs to access it, it obtains the lock of that variable, reads or writes to it, and then releases the lock.

The quite bad part of this is that all threads are dependent on one single resource - which could make the whole application slower than nescessary - one request could lock the config variable and all the others came to a halt when they needed to read it. Deadlock.

Maybe it's good enough for debugging, though.

More about locking of resources here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816161

*The better thing* (avoiding deadlocks) would be to use an immutable data structure, which nowadays seem to be available through [NuGet ImmutableHashMap](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx)